# async function does weird thing first after reinstantiating the object where it is called

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Going to try my best to explain it as wel as possible. 
So I'm making a mind puzzle game where you flip 2 cards, if their colours match they stay flipped, otherwise they flip back to their original state.

For my gametable I used an html table which I fill in trough js

HTML:

```
<body>
<button id="start">New Game</button>
    <table id="gametable">

    </table>
<p>Turns: <span id="amntTurns"></span></p>
    <p>Your Record: <span id="record"></span></p>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i = 0; i < GRID_HEIGHT; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < GRID_WIDTH; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.className = 'flip-container';
                (function(i, j, activeElements, self){
                    td.addEventListener('click', function eventListening(ev){...});
                })(i, j, proto.activeElements, this);

                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            fragment.appendChild(tr);
        }
        table.appendChild(fragment);
```

I know that using an HTML table might not be as ideal as a Canvas, but half the point of this exercise is to get better at HTML and CSS too.

Any time 2 items don't match the following code gets executed.

```
if(!self.uiListener.lastFound){
    proto.updateUI(['red','red'],false);
}
updateUI : function (colors, asc) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.targets.length; i++) {
                animate(this.targets[i], colors[i], asc);
                }
            }
function animate(element, color,asc) {

    var pos;
    if(asc){
        pos = 0;
    }else{
        pos = 10;
    }
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if ((pos == 10 && asc)||(pos == 0 && !asc)) {
            clearInterval(id);

        } else {
            if(asc){
                pos++;
            }else{
                pos--
            }

            element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + pos + 'deg)';
            element.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```

this all works the first time my Game and my GameView have been instantiated.

Now to the problem:
If I start a new Game for the second time the first turn my mismatched cards do go back to their original state(they rotate back), but for some reason the background color keeps the color their 'back side' has.

I never call the animate function in a descending way with any other color than red so I'm clueless as to why this might be happening.

The code can be found an tested in the following [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/oPOTuuzX1bH6D2VlJiY9)

Start game twice and then flip 3 cards.

Comment: `this all works the first time my Game and my GameView have been instantiated.` .... that's very interesting ... and where are these Game and GameView things you speak of? They don't appear in the code you posted

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't want to flood the question with 1000 lines of code so I added the source in a plunk which can be found in the question. everything gets instantiated in the newGame() function

Comment: sure ... did you notice the `TypeError: gameview.prototype is undefined` error? - because ... `GameView` has a prototype, but the instantiated `gameview = new GameView()` would not. Any other errors in the **developer** tools console?

Comment: I sure have, it's a remaining of when I tried to debug and change some things to try and find the problem, the code which is causing it has been edited back to its original state. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: put `console.log(color, asc, element)` as the first line of `animate` function ... you'll see what's happening

Comment: something isn't right with `targets`

Comment: I'm looking into it. Thank you very much, I will make sure to post when I have found the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found the answer and it had absolutely nothing to do with the async function.

I had my targets which had to change state defined in the prototype of my GameView.
When reinstantiating my Gameview the targets array in there didn't reset which caused it to have a length of 4.

The colors array only has 2 colors so the actual targets that needed change received undefined as color which caused them to keep their original color.